# Puxar dados de uma página

Tags: php, html

estou tentando puxar o nome e a data de nascimento dos meus clientes a partir da minha página WEB, mas está puxando apenas o saldo e não o nome (PHP).

> PARTE PHP

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://conta.ebanx.com/api/v1/timeline');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Host: conta.ebanx.com',
            'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Connection: keep-alive',
            'Authorization: Bearer '.$token.''
            ));

    $d5 = curl_exec($ch);
    $saldo = getstr($d5, 'balance":', ',');
    $nome = getstr($d5, 'full_name":', ',');
    if (strpos($d5, '{"name":"')) {
        print ("<font><font style='color: lime;'>INFO ✓ $nome » $saldo </font>");
    } else {
```

---

> PARTE HTML

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><script>dataLayer = [{
  'short_name': "Talita",
  'full_name': "Talita Aranda",
  'locale': "pt-BR",
  'balance': "1.43",
  'balance_formatted': "US$ 1,43",
  'status_account': "Active",
  'has_edc': "No"
}];
```

"Ah, mais porquê puxar esses dados dos clientes autenticados ?" R: Isto é para ajuda na economia do saldo dos mesmos, sempre contatando-os sobre quaisquer consultas

Comment: Olá, Isabela. Bem-vinda ao StackOverflow. Para podermos ajudar, forneca mais informações sobre o código e o problema. Por exemplo: o que o CURL está retornando?

Comment: Tem como você postar todo o conteudo de `$d5`?

Comment: Editei o tópico drasticamente!

Comment: Não entendo de curl, mas acho que você está fazendo essa requisição de forma errada. Não é correto retornar o header, somente o json do body.

Comment: tô aguardando por outras respostas

Comment: A função `getstr()` não parece ser nativa do php. Sem saber como é a implementação dela fica dificil identificar o problema.